# Do any particles exist which are NOT entangled with another?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Please accept my apologies for a neophyte question

Do we have evidence that suggests whether a subatomic particle can exist which is NOT entangled (correlated) with at least one other particle in the universe?

Are there reasons this cannot be possible? 
Are there reasons this would be possible?

Comment: Depends on how uncorrelated two systems need to be before you call them "not entangled".

Comment: Are you talking about practical situations, or theoretical ones (such as situations where we can constrain a particle for an infinite period of time)?

Comment: @CortAmmon - I was referring to any degree of entanglement.

Comment: I'm wary of answering, because your question asks about the mathematical limit of the most extreme corner case you can imagine, so it's easy to be surprised there.  However, I don't believe there is any way to 100% decorelate two particles without an infinite supply of additional particles in a "random state."  The concept of a particle in a "random state" is a modeling phrase, not a physically real thing.  However, *practically* speaking, there are absolutely two particles which cannot be distinguished from being uncorrelated by any realistic measurement.

Answer (score 2):

A system of two spins: the state $\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\mid#1\rangle}\ket{\uparrow}\!\ket{\uparrow}$ is not entangled. In case you wonder what that notation means: the first spin up and the second spin up.

As opposed to the state $\ket{\uparrow}\ket{\downarrow}+\ket{\downarrow}\ket{\uparrow}$ which is a superposition of two states: (1) the first spin up and the second spin down, and (2) the first spin down and the second spin up. That is entangled.

Either of those two states are easily produced by modern light sources.

Comment: Thank-you for your replies.   The recent demonstration/detection of entanglement of a large group of atoms (approx 16 million) sparked my question.  https://phys.org/news/2017-10-photon-reveals-quantum-entanglement-million.html

Comment: I see! Notice that if those were Carbon atoms, this would be $3.2\times 10^{-16}$ grams: 16 millions atoms is very little matter…

Comment: @luc-j-bourhis - :)